# What kind of a package is flafter?

Tags: packages

I didn't find any reference to this package on CTAN. Is it a builtin? Does it have any documentation?

Comment: The `flafter` package is included in the base LaTeX distribution. It should be described in the LaTeX manual, but I don't have it at hand now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It [appears](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-floats.html) it is a LaTeX builtin. There doesn't seem to be any documentation. Loading the package with `\usepackage` has the effect that floats always appear after their definition.