# How to flush floats without beginning a new page AFTER the float

Tags: floats

I want to flush my float (after an obviously necessary pre-pagebreak, since otherwise the float would be printed there anyway) and continue the text right below this flushed float **with no additional page break *after* the float**. My question is, if I have done this correctly.

**The problem:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{I am a figure}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

**I was curious, if there exists something like `\flush`:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{I am a figure}
\end{figure}

\flush %error

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

**My current solution:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float} %does this only affect the single figure with 'H'?

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{figure}[H] %is this the right way?
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{I am a figure}
\end{figure}

%\clearpage %this is wrong

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: In this context, what do you mean by the word "flush"?

Comment: As you are using [H] there is nothing to flush.

Comment: `\lipsum[2]` appears twice (first time part of `1-3`.  I presume you mean the 2nd instance?

Comment: As it currently stands, the figure *does* print before `\lipsum[2]`...just not on page 1.  There is no room on page 1 for an `H` non-"float" of this size.

Comment: if you want the figure to be there, [H] could be okay, the alternative is the placeins package and its \FloatBarrier command.

Comment: I'm deleting my comments (including this one). See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1477/should-we-clean-up-obsolete-comments

Comment: if you want there to be text below the float why use the optional argument to explictly prevent top floats? (normally latex warns about `[h]` and changes it to `[ht]`)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle using `[ht]` also results in `\lipsum[2]` being print on the first page, which I do not want (call in mind, that this is a MWE. `\lipsum[2]` actually is a new section)

Comment: better to use the `flafter` package than rely on latex's error recovery if you don't want floats to float to the top of the current page.

Comment: Is there a documentation of `flafter`? Can't find one on CTAN

Comment: [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261542/what-kind-of-a-package-is-flafter) it sounds like `flafter` affects **all** floats but not a specific one

Comment: I think if you ensure the pending floats at that point use `!` and include `t` or just `[!h]` which is converted to `[!ht]` at the next page, then  you can use `\newpage` and all floats should be output as there are no constraints stopping them being output as top floats.

Comment: actually previous comment doesn't quite work but may be the basis of a solution

Answer (score 1):

The credit goes to [Ulrike](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer)'s comment and [James](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/70641/james)'s one respectively [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88659/110154).

(`\afterpage{\clearpage}` doesn't do what I want (as I tried))

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{placeins}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{I am a figure\label{fig:one}}
\end{figure}

\FloatBarrier

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: while this works in this case (as `\FloatBarrier` just did `\newpage`) in the usual case it does `\clearpage` and so will force a page break after the flushed floats.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't get your comment

Comment: In the code above you can replace `\FloatBarrier` by `\newpage` and get the same output. generally `\newpage` does _not_ flush all pending floats it just got lucky here and this float is output. `\FloatBarrier` tries that first, then if (as usually happens) the pending floats have not been output, it does `\clearpage` which flushes the floats, forcing a page break afterwards.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ok, this is actually sad, as I would expect `\FloatBarrier` to flush all floats and then continue the following content/text on the same (last) page. This means, the only advantage of `\FloatBarrier` is that I don't have to chose myself between `\newpage` and `\clearpage`

Comment: floatbarrier is only a dozen lines of code: `if no floats do nothing else try \newpage  if still floats \clearpage fi fi`

Comment: to see what I mean, duplicate the figure so there are two pending floats, you will then see `\clearpage` in action.

Comment: I already tried that

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you are correct, \FloatBarrier is creating a new page for me. Is there an alternative to clear the floats without running the risk of a \clearpage being used?

Comment: @nicolejane33 basically, no, but try `fewerfloatpages`  package)